# Append dictionaries to List with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have data within a for loop that is parsing XML. I will not get into the code of the loop because i believe it is irrelevant in this situation.

At the end of the loop are dictionaries such as the ones below. The count varies on how many times I have looped through. This variable is called cargroup.

```
{colour: 'red', make: 'Ford', model: 'Focus'}
{colour: 'blue', make: 'VW', model: 'GTI'}
```

When i print the cargroup dictionary type i get this

```
 <dict>
 <dict>
```

and length

```
  3
  3
```

I want to add the cargroup dictionary to a list so that my output looks as so

```
 [{colour: 'red', make: 'Ford', model: 'Focus'}, {colour: 'blue', make: 'VW', model: 'GTI'}]
```

To do so I am doing adding them a list called cargrouplist with the below code:

```
cargrouplist.append(cargroup)
```

My problem is that instead of getting my desired output (reference above), I am getting this:

```
     [{colour: 'blue', make: 'VW', model: 'GTI'}, {colour: 'blue', make: 'VW', model: 'GTI'}]
```

Why am i getting this output and how can i fix?

Comment: I imagine you're not updating your `cargroup` to match the current dictionary while iterating over them (or parsing them out of your XML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cargrouplist.append(cargroup)` does not make a copy of the dictionary, so its contents is overwritten during the next loop iteration.  You either need to create a new dictionary for each iteration (maybe set `cargroup = {}`, or add a (shallow) copy to the list using `cargrouplist.append(cargroup.copy())`.

Comment: cargroup is being initialized at the beginning of the loop, so i am setting cargroup = {}